# MonteCarlo Value At Risk for futures portfolio

Tags: futures, monte-carlo, risk-management, value-at-risk, commodities

I wanted to ask, suppose I have a portfolio of futures of gasoline and other oil products eg ULSD (*Ultra Low Sulphur Diesel*), WTI (*West Texas Intermediate*) for different months. I want to compute the MonteCarlo value at risk for the positions in the portfolio. To calibrate the MonteCarlo simulations, should I use the time series of the Future expiring in the corresponding month in the corresponding product but the year before? Eg for nov 22 ulsd should I use the nov 21 ulsd future prices to calibrate the MonteCarlo simulation ?

Thank you for the help

Comment: This may help somewhat https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/19181